# java SSL socket using a known shared key

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, encryption, tcp

I have a setup where I have multiple computers/nodes communicating over a LAN with TCP running on the java 8 runtime. They all know a single shared key which is the same for all computers. The key is known only at runtime. The goal is to encrypt the communication over TCP with the shared key. Both the encryption and decryption must be possible from the shared key.

I'd like to use the java Socket class for TCP communication among the nodes, so the java SSLSocket class seems like the logical solution but I'm not sure how to set it up to use simply a shared key known by the nodes on either end. As far as I understand the SSLSocket uses certificates to authenticate the other end but I don't see how to adapt It to use a shared key.

Comment: Java's SSL api does not support what are called "preshared" keys. It appears that the Bouncycastle java library does based on [some classes](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/tls/PSKTlsClient.html) there, but I've never tried it. You would to have both client and server components that support SSL/TLS with preshared keys.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to enforce the ssl socket working other way than it does. IMHO it would require more work and workarounds than extending your own socket or stream achieving the stated goal

> The goal is to encrypt the communication over TCP with the shared key.

I'd try to keep it simple. Maybe having a customized stream (or channel)  which would send/receive a random IV for cipher initialization and then using some stream cipher (or ctr cipher mode) would do the job. Inded this
approach would not ensure data integrity itself.

if you are ok to extend the security providers, as already commented, you could use the [BC PSK TLS](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/r1rv69/tls/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/tls/PSKTlsClient.java) which is more robust than the simple option above

Comment: The Link is death

Comment: The link has been fixed.